# Limited bit depth display for GUI Software

Tags: x11, gtk

I have an old computer which can only display a limited number of colours (8bit or 1bit).  When I use it as an X terminal for my Linux system the windows look (at best) horrible or (at worst) are unusable because of the dithering that takes place.

When I first started using Unix, 25 years ago, there were perfectly fine window managers which used limited numbers of colours, and there were applications which didn't attempt to use large numbers of colours to display their interfaces.

GTK+ seems to be the problem in this instance (which is unusual, because normally GTK+ is a very good answer to most GUI design questions on Unix/Linux!).

What software is available today for email, internet, IRC, word processing, spreadsheet and so forth which will work well with a hugely constrained palette - which probably means written without the benefit of GTK+, just using basic X Windows or original 80s style GTK?

Thank you for any suggestions that you might have!

Comment: 1 bit = monochrome, 8 bit = 256 colors... Not sure, but maybe relevant: https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/performance-17.html.en